# Same option_id=0 for 2 options in wp_options?

Tags: mysql, options

What does it mean when (according to mySQL Workbench) 2 options have option_id = 0?

Just noticed this for unrelated plugin and theme holding very different options.

*Update* Just noticed over 200 options had id 0 (`select * from wordpress.wp_options where option_id = 0`) on one test system. What causes this, and could this be a reason transients seem to be deleted early?

Comment: What's the table structure of `wp_options` ? Try `DESCRIBE wordpress.wp_options` The `option_id` should be a primary key, so I'm surprised that it's not unique.

Comment: I see option_name has key=UNI, nothing else in the key column.

Comment: On another WP setup I see PRI key, auto_increment. Why do some installs not have that set?

Comment: @Saikat That may have been it. Were you also using Windows 8 and Xampp?

Comment: I have moved the comment into answer. I was using Windows7 and Xampp. @NoBugs

Answer (score 2):

If we check how the `wp_options` table is created (in 4.4) from the `schema.php` file, we will find the following:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->options (
  option_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  option_name varchar(191) NOT NULL default '',
  option_value longtext NOT NULL,
  autoload varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY  (option_id),
  UNIQUE KEY option_name (option_name)
) $charset_collate;
```

Here's how this structure looks like for the `wp_options` table:

```
> DESCRIBE wp_options;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| option_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option_name  | varchar(191)        | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| option_value | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| autoload     | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | yes     |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

If this happened just recently you should check your error logs for PHP, MySQL, NginX/Apache.

Not sure what your MySQL version is, but the [recommended](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) version is 5.6+ but should work on 5.0+.

Make sure the table structure of the other core tables is intact as well.

Remember to **backup** your database before altering the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same type of issue when I imported my database via phpmyadmin. I think, if you have a database backup, then you can try another re-import operation vaia phpmyadmin. That worked for me, but not sure if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you import the database on your phpmyadmin.  It has an option while importing sql  files. `Don't use AUTO_INCREMENT for null tables or zero rows`.   This option just above the go button.  Read this checkbox and mark it based on your choice.  Than import your database.  It won't be the problem.  The `option_ID` is an primary key and it's AUTO_INCREMENT.

If you are using phpmyadmin.  Go-to the options table and it's structure view.  Than make it primary key and edit the field and check the AUTO_INCREMENT in it.  Than your prblem will be solved.